# GCM not working on Gingerbread, but is working on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a game that uses GCM messages.  When one player enters turn moves to the server, the server will send a GCM message to their opponent letting that client know that additional turn data is available.  This should be simple.  I have followed the sample GCM client code as closely as possible.

I have two devices for testing:
A Motorola Xoom with Ice Cream Sandwich version 4.0.4
A Motorola X2 with Gingerbread version 2.3.5

Both devices have a Goggle account setup (in fact, the same account).  I can download applications from the Play Store on both.  I get notification messages on both when I receive a new Google Talk message or Gmail message.  They are both in front of me using the same Wi-Fi network, so I can confirm there are no firewall issues.  I have the same game application installed on both.  I have been able to get a GCM registration ID number on both devices.  Aside from the Android OS version, both devices are virtually identical.  However, the Xoom will receive GCM messages and the X2 does not, or at least the messages are not being broadcast to my application on the X2.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="myGame.app.main" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="myGame.app.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="myGame.app.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="myGameApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:description="@string/description" android:theme="@style/GlobalTheme" android:killAfterRestore="false" android:allowTaskReparenting="false" android:persistent="false">

    ... Other Activities ...

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="myGame.app.main" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is code for my GCMIntentService:

```
package myGame.app.main;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock sWakeLock;
    private static final Object LOCK = GCMIntentService.class;
    private static final String GCM_SENDER_ID = "... My Sender ID...";
    private static final String GCM_INTENT_FILTER = "myGame.app.main.GCM_MESSAGE";
    private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE = "Type";
    private static final String MESSAGE_CONTENT = "Body";
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GCMIntentService.class.getName());

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super(GCM_SENDER_ID);
    }

    static void runIntentInService(Context context,Intent intent)
    {
        synchronized(LOCK)
        {
            if (sWakeLock == null)
            {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"sc_wakelock");
            }
        }
        sWakeLock.acquire();
        intent.setClassName(context,GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override protected void onRegistered(Context context,String registrationId)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Device successfully registered as "+registrationId);
        ... Other Code ...
    }

    @Override protected void onUnregistered(Context context,String registrationId)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Device successfully unregistered");
        ... Other Code ...
    }

    @Override protected void onMessage(Context context,Intent messageIntent)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Game update notice received");
        ... Other Code ...
    }

    @Override protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context,int total)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Server deleted "+Integer.toString(total)+" pending messages");
    }

    @Override public void onError(Context context,String errorId)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Error "+errorId);
        ... Other Code ...
    }

    @Override protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context,String errorId)
    {
        log.warning("From GCMIntentService: Recoverable error "+errorId);
        return(super.onRecoverableError(context,errorId));
    }
}
```

I have even gone as far as creating my own GCMBroadcastReceiver class with my own getGCMIntentServiceClassName() function, and put a log message there.  In every variation I have tried, I see the proper LogCat messages when the application is running on the Xoom, but I see no evidence of any GCM messages at all on the X2.  It is as if the GCMBroadcastReceiver and/or GCMIntentService are not functioning at all, but I see no error messages of any kind.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I also forgot to mention, I am using the latest gcm.jar file which was released a few days ago.

Comment: You could try running on an emulator with the Google Apis for additional test cases. If it works on a ICS emulator and doesn't on a 2.3.3 you can at least confirm that it's the version of Android that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  It inspired me to do something similar which led me to the answer.  I'll post the solution momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the sample code for GCM messages.  The only changes I made were to use the same API key and Sender ID that I'm using in my game application.  This application works on both devices, so I can reconfirm there are no network issues and I can confirm that the X2 actually can receive GCM messages.

The bad news was that the X2 still did not receive GCM messages for my game. After more research I discovered that when the server tries to send a GCM message to the X2 (for my game application only) the server receives an ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED result.  There is no such error sending to the Xoom.  I have confirmed that the server is successfully receiving the registration ID numbers.  I know it's hard to tell, but the registration IDs do not get mangled in the transmission process.

I tried a few different published recommendations on how to unregister the device from the GCM server but none seemed to work.  I always received the same registration ID back again.  So I completely uninstalled my game then reinstalled it on the X2.  That forced it to get a new registration ID number which solved the problem.  My game works properly on both devices now.  I must assume that somehow the registration ID got mixed up somehow, between the game and GCM server, while I was debugging.

I can only hope that this doesn't become a regular problem, as there doesn't seem to be a successful fix other than uninstalling the application.