# registerReceiver Does not work

Tags: android

I'm trying to deal with push notifications in my main class (and i also have GCMBroadcastReceiver - for all the notifications that comes when i'm not running the main class)

but the registerReceiver Does not work 
(GCMBroadcasrReceiver works fine)

my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"));
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("BroadcastReceiver","Working");
        }
    };

}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*Works fine only in my 4.1.2 (S3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659784/gcm-not-working-on-gingerbread-but-is-working-on-ice-cream-sandwich)?

Comment: in my app the GCMBroadcastReceiver works fine, but the registerReceiver doesn't...

Comment: if you look at https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/ , this class is deprecated. It's suggested to use GCM instead. But if you can't. Make sure your 2.3.5 system has logged on a valid google account at least once. It's one of the prerequisite in order to work. It's easy to forget if you try that on a simulator.

Comment: @SylvainHuard - i'm using GCM and not c2dm, the action "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" is used in GCM - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, found the solution:

in my GCMIntentService.java i need to set sendBroadcast like so:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent("com.my.app.DISPLAY_PUSH");

        i.putExtra("msg", intent.getExtras().getString("msg"));
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```

and the BroadcastReceiver should be

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.my.app.DISPLAY_PUSH"));
    }
.
.
.

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BroadcastReceiver","Working with msg:" + intent.getExtras().getString("msg")  );
        }
};
```

I wonder why it works in 4.1.2 without the sendBroadcast...

Answer (score 1):

if you call sendBroadcast like this

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(context, mBroadcastReceiver.getClass());
intent.setAction(ACTION_ON_CLICK);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);

// or

Intent  intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_ON_CLICK);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

change it to this :

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(ACTION_ON_CLICK);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```