# GCM no receive messages in 2.3.6 but it's ok in 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

The problem is only with android 2.3.6 .
With 4.x, there isn't any problem, the receiver it's ok.
I have received the registration ID with 2.3.6 but the messages are never received.

My Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.arte.biluna”
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="net.arte.biluna.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="net.arte.biluna.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="net.arte.biluna.businesslogic.CosmoApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >

    <!-- android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" > -->
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.GreatestActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.LogInActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.HomePage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.LiveTourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.ChatActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.ForYouActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.StoreActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service android:name="net.arte.biluna.GcmIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="net.arte.biluna.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="net.arte.biluna" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

My receiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

my activity:

```
...
if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.equals("")) {
                registerInBackground();
            }

        }
...

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14716868/1025599

Comment: With new version of GCM, it doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the Google play services version number and there is a pretty defined method to check Google play services a availability

Answer (score 0):

Latest release of gcm using google play is very easy to implement and can be used for longer time.

See this tutorial. Hope it might help.

> http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/